# How to get a cartesian-product of all pair from two vectors in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

This is almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541401/pairwise-crossproduct-in-python), but in numpy, and for matrices over some dimension:

I have two matrices of length n, `A` and `B`, for example,

```
n = 1000
A = np.random.rand(n, 3, 4, 5)
B = np.random.rand(n, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want a new matrix `C`, in which every element (`C[i]`) is a matrix of shape `(2, 3, 4, 5)`: `C[i][0]` is `A[k]`, and `C[i][0]` is `B[k]` for some `k`, where elements from `A` and `B` are selected once for every other element in the other.

A more concrete example:

```
A = [elem1, elem2, elem3]
B = [elem4, elem5, elem6]
```

then

```
C = [
[elem1, elem4],[elem1, elem5],[elem1, elem6],
[elem2, elem4],[elem2, elem5],[elem2, elem6],
[elem3, elem4],[elem3, elem5],[elem3, elem6]
]
```

I am aware I can use itertools to build this, but i figured it already exists, and faster.

Comment: Check the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971397/for-loop-using-more-than-one-list-in-python It might help you!

Comment: What you're describing is the Cartesian product, not the cross product (might be the reason you didn't find the solution yourself). [This beautiful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points) offers a solution with numpy-builtins as well as a bountied implementation of what the author calls an "almost canonical Cartesian product"

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @divakar will check on sunday when im back at work. Dont worry

Comment: @Gulzar Gentle reminder - Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a simpler understanding point of view, an assignment based would make sense. Hence -

```
dt = np.result_type(A.dtype,B.dtype)
s = A.shape
C = np.empty((s[0],)+(2,)+s[1:],dtype=dt)
C[:,0] = A
C[:,1] = B
```

This could be simplified with a stacking operation for a one-liner -

```
C = np.stack((A,B),axis=1)
```

Bit of explanation on how these two methods solve it :

The one-liner is basically stacking A after B. In the first approach, the resultant is a 2 element ndarray along the second axis - s[0],)+(2,)+s[1:]. Thus, each element off A and off B are interleaved along that axis. This stacking operation has a NumPy builtin np.stack, which is the second method. Hence, these two are equivalent and solve our case.

And some verification :

Question is asking for - `a new matrix C, in which every element (C[i]) is a matrix of shape (2, 3, 4, 5)`. Hence, `C` would be of shape `(n,2,3,4,5)`. The stacking is along the second axis. Furthermore, from what I have understood, the question is asking for `C[k][0]` == `A[k]` for `k=0..n` and `C[k][1]` == `B[k]` for `k=0..n`. Let's prove that -

```
In [323]: n = 1000
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n, 3, 4, 5)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(n, 3, 4, 5)

In [324]: C = np.stack((A,B),axis=1)

In [325]: np.all([np.allclose(C[i][0],A[i]) for i in range(1000)])
Out[325]: True

In [326]: np.all([np.allclose(C[i][1],B[i]) for i in range(1000)])
Out[326]: True
```

Comment: Please explain why the one liner is equivalent to the 5-liner, and how does it provide all the pairs?

Comment: @Gulzar Added comments. Does that answer your question?